# I've just found a time-based background change but can't repeat it

Tags: javascript, html, css

The strangest thing is that everyting works great with document.body.style.background, so I don't understand why can't Icahnge the style of this div

Here's the code:

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");

var showTime = function() {
    var time = new Date,
        hours = time.getHours().toString(),
        minutes = time.getMinutes().toString(),
        seconds = time.getSeconds().toString();


    if (hours < 10) {
        hours = "0" + hours;
    }
    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }
    if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }

    wrapper.style.background = "#" + hours + minutes + seconds;

}

setInterval(showTime, 1000);
```

Comment: Best guess: this code is located before the wrapper element so it doesn't exist yet when you assign it to the variable. Are there errors in the browser's error console?

Comment: ensure your html actually has a div with id wrapper. Try using `console.log(wrapper)` after you define `wrapper`. Do you see your div in console? Is this called in a page load wrapper or at the end of the doc? it may be your element isn't on the page when the js runs.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Lkr3u8ue/ but I agree with @Juhana. If you have this script before your element you'll be in trouble.

Comment: @Juhana is spot on. I actuallty tried your js code in a quick html file and it works fine, as long as it's AFTER your <div id="wrapper"></div>

Comment: Tried your code in a jsfiddle, works fine. You don't see a color change because it's such a subtle change, as @michaelgarner stated below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is working just fine, but to clarify what you are doing to the background object you could explicitly say "backgroundColor"

The problem you may be running into is that you are setting a HEX color for the background every second, but you wouldn't notice any drastic changes every second because the colors are too similar. You can get browser extensions to detect colors like:
ColorZillas Chrome Extension.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/colorzilla/bhlhnicpbhignbdhedgjhgdocnmhomnp

The red shades are only being modified every hour and only by a single digit at that, the green every minute and again only by a single digit. The blue changes the most, but it's still hard to notice a difference unless you screen shot at the start and again after like 15 seconds or so.

This also only utilizes a small subset of the color spectrum because the amounts wouldn't ever exceed 60 in HEX, and in the case of hours it wouldn't exceed either 12 or 24.

If you are looking for a bigger change every second you could work out some math on the seconds and use rgb or convert to hex. This way you are changing 3-4 shades every second instead of just one.

Example:

```
var percentOfMin = seconds/60;
var blue = Math.round(255 * percentOfMin);
```

Etc. etc.

```
style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + ")";
```

This way every second works an even part of then entire blue spectrum, minutes for green, and hours for red.